# How to properly add Headers in Angular?

Tags: angular, http-headers

Here is the service code in Angular:

```
getcareer(dataout:any){
   let headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'application/json').append('Authorization','Bearer'+' '+GlobalService.authtoken);
  //headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json').append('Authorization','Bearer'+' '+GlobalService.authtoken);
  //let headers={'Authorization':'Bearer'+' '+GlobalService.authtoken}
  console.log(headers);
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/employee/getcareer',
  {'headers': headers })
  .subscribe(data => {
    dataout = data});
}
```

Now after logging in and trying to access this page, it says 401, Unauthorized. In the browser console, The headers are added in the LazyUpdate section instead of the headers section. I have tried `.set` `.append` and some other methods but no luck. Please have a look, thankyou.

Edit:
Here is a detailed console in browser (I have printed the httpheaders here in console log):

https://ibb.co/f002tZ9

Above is the link to the image (sorry there is an issue posting an image here). You can see the Headers are not present in 'header' section but in 'lazyupdate' section.

Comment: i think you should not print the headers but look what actually is send over the network. You can user the Browser Network tab so see the request and debug. Probably the headers are correct

Comment: @Zerotwelve Thankyou. I have seen the headers in network section. But the Authorization header is neither present in the request headers, nor in the response headers. But the 'Content-Type' header is present there automatically even if i don't mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [POST doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) the second param is the data:

```js
/** POST: add a new hero to the database */
addHero(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

So in your case, you have to:

```js
  getcareer(dataout:any){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'application/json').append('Authorization','Bearer'+' '+GlobalService.authtoken);
    console.log(headers);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/employee/getcareer',
    null,
    {headers }) //unncessary key-value
    .subscribe(data => dataout = data);
}
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, I have tried many similar options too but same result

Comment: Inspect the request over the network tab, probably the request is correct

Comment: I have seen the request payload section. Through one method, the headers are present in LazyUpdate section (using ```new headers().set``` method). Through another method, the header is present inside another header. like an object within an object. But none of the methods work i have tried till yet work.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz? Your behavior is really strange

Comment: Behaviour is strange? Kindly elaborate? Moreover I am trying Stackblitz(I am a new developer so don't know much).

Comment: Nope, isn't elaborate, is just strange that you can't see the headers in your request

Comment: I have seen Postman headers that are used by default when a request is sent. those headers also include ```'X-Powered-By'``` and ```'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'```. I have added them too but still the same issue.

Comment: Shifenis here, check the Headers and Request Payload section in Network: https://ibb.co/d5wsjhz

Comment: This is wrong, what are you seeing is the HTTP body, you should see under the `Headers` tab

Comment: Shifenis there are 2 images in the link above, the first image is the headers tab in the network section.

Comment: Shifenis i saw your ```null``` in the body section and now I know that in a POST request you have to put body first and then the headers. but I copied your code and it didn't work 2 days ago. But now it works too! thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
const options = {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + GlobalService.authtoken
  }
};

this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/employee/getcareer', options)
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, I have tried many similar options too but same result

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. the thing is that you have to pass headers differently for POST requests and GET requests. Normally i have found solutions that were for GET requests I assume.
For POST request I found a solution over the web as well as here:

```
  const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer '+GlobalService.authtoken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };


  return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/employee/getcareer/',body,{headers}).subscribe(data => {
    this.dataout = data});
```

so right after the URL, body comes in a POST request and then the headers. If there is no body then leave `null` there and then put headers. Where as in a GET request, no body comes and headers are put right after the URL.